# Why is Hoshimiya Kate's Seifuku Jikan weak against Tobacco?

Tags: world-conquest-zvezda-plot

During the series, whenever Kate tries to use her Seifuku Jikan on smokers, the attack fails to conquer the target.

[image]

[image]

There are several other moments when smoke and smokers are shown to have an effect on the Zvezda team:

[image]

One theory is that what the enemies are smoking is quite not tobacco...

what is going on?

Comment: I think it is a natural weakness of Udo or anything that runs on Udo.

Comment: Didn't watch the anime at all, but researching suggests that it's Zvesda's weak point (or natural weakness, or..). The discussion on 2chan also suggests "a battle between smokers vs anti-smokers team" (probably reflecting ep. 3).